# Python: How to construct a joyplot with values taken from a column in pandas dataframe as y axis

Tags: python, plot

I have a dataframe df in which the column extracted_day consists of dates ranging between 2022-05-08 to 2022-05-12. I have another column named gas_price, which consists of the price of the gas. I want to construct a joyplot such that for each date, it shows the gas_price in the y axis and has minutes_elapsed_from_start_of_day in the x axis. We may also use ridgeplot or any other plot if this doesn't work.

[image]

This is the code that I have written, but it doesn't serve my purpose.

```
from joypy import joyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df['extracted_day'] = df['extracted_day'].astype(str)
joyplot(df, by = 'extracted_day', column = 'minutes_elapsed_from_start_of_day',figsize=(14,10))
plt.xlabel("Number of minutes elapsed throughout the day")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Check out the section "Plotting with pre-aggregated data" in this notebook: https://github.com/leotac/joypy/blob/master/Joyplot.ipynb

Comment: @Flursch Can you please explain how can we modify the program with respect to our context.

Answer (score 0):

Create dataframe with mock data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from joypy import joyplot

np.random.seed(111)

df = pd.DataFrame({
'minutes_elapsed_from_start_of_day': np.tile(np.arange(1440), 5),
'extracted_day': np.repeat(['2022-05-08', '2022-05-09', '2022-05-10','2022-05-11', '2022-05-12'], 1440),
'gas_price': abs(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(1440*5)))})
```

Then create the joyplot. It is important that you set `kind='values'`, since you do not want joyplot to show KDEs (kernel density estimates, joyplot's default) but the raw `gas_price` values:

```py
joyplot(df, by='extracted_day',
            column='gas_price',
            kind='values',
            x_range=np.arange(1440),
            figsize=(7,5))
```

The resulting joyplot looks like this (the fake gas prices are represented by the y-values of the lines):
[image]

Comment: How do we ensure that the x axis consists of data from the column minutes_elapsed_from_the_start_of_the_day

Comment: As is said in the documentation notebook for the joypy library (linked above), this requires some manual work (section: "Plotting with pre-aggregated data"). You probably have to extract the `minutes_elapsed_from_the_start_of_the_day` from `df` and pass it to the `x_range` parameter of the `joyplot` function. I cannot do that for you, since I do not have your dataframe. But it seems that you also have to do some aggregation, because you have multiple different `gas_price` values for the same `block_timestamp` (which seems a bit weird to me).